# PHP fopen script read line

Tags: php, fopen, counter, fwrite

I've created a small script that opens a text document, increments a number each time a user opens a specific page and writes the new number on the next line in the document. I would like the script to be able to read the last line of the document and increment that number. Currently, it continues to look at the first line and increment the first number entered.

```
function job_number_script(){
    $job_data = "";
    $user_info = $_SESSION['user_info'];
    $user_id = $user_info['user']['id'];
    $job_id = "";
    //Initialize the return
    $job_number_page = ("job_setup.txt");
    $job_number = file($job_number_page);
    $work = explode(",",$job_number[0]);
    $work[0]++;
    $job_id = $work[0]++;
    $work2 = array($job_id, $user_id);
    $works = implode(",",$work2);
    $fp = fopen($job_number_page, "a+");
    fputs($fp, "$works\n");
    fclose($fp);
    $job_data = $job_id;
    return $job_data;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way could be that you just replace all occurrences of $work[0] with $work[count($work)-1].

Comment: I actually had to edit $job_number, but this worked as well thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `file()` to read each line into an array:

```
 $lines = file($job_number_page);
 $lines[count($lines)-1]++;
 $data = implode("", $lines);
 // write data to file again
 file_put_contents($job_number_page, $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this directly by using couple of php functions, [`fseek()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php), [`ftell()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftell.php), [`fgetc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetc.php) and [`fgets()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) (the first part of script will just set the file pointer to last line):

```
$fp = fopen( 'file.txt', 'a+') or die('Failed to open file: file.txt');

// Way 1
fseek( $fp, SEEK_END, 0); // Go to the end of file
$max = ftell( $fp); // Get max/end position
for( $i = $max-1; $i >= 0; $i--){
    fseek( $fp, $i, SEEK_SET);
    if( fgetc( $fp) == "\n")){
        break;
    }
}

// Way 2
$length = 0;
while( ($row = fgets( $fp)) !== false){
    $length = strlen( $row);
}
fseek( $fp, -$length, SEEK_CUR);
```

Now you have file pointer at beginning of the last line, now you need to read the last line and move file back to be able to rewrite it.

```
$pos = ftell( $fp);
$line = trim( fgets( $fp));
fseek( $fp, $pos, SEEK_SET);
```

And now increment, rewrite and save:

```
fwrite( $fp, $line+1);
fclose($fp);
```

I strictly **recommend** using [`flock()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) like this:

```
$fp = fopen( 'file.txt', 'a+') or die('Failed to open file: file.txt');
if( !flock($fp, LOCK_EX)){
    fclose( $fp);
    die( 'Cannot get exclusive lock: file.txt');
}

// The code mentioned above
flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
fclose( $fp);
```

*Note:* the example above (with `fwrite( $fp, $line+1)`) works only if you're writing "strings" with equal or longer length, if you need to write shorter string you need to use [`ftruncate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftruncate.php).